# Split the time given based on the number of digits

Tags: java, validation, date, datetime

I have string which holds a time.

For example,

String time = "11235678";

The above time is in HH MM SS MS (Hours, Minutes, Seconds, Milliseconds).

There is no guarantee that seconds and milliseconds are received all the time but if I receive it I must split accordingly.

Now I know we can use the length split the string but I want to know if there is any better way of doing it?

Cheeers!!!

Comment: based on the length decide *format* of input and use `SimpleDateFormat` to parse & **validate** the input

Comment: Yes that is what I'm doing it already. But I'm looking for better way to do it :)

Comment: What is wrong with suggested way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will split the input by 2 digits

```
String[] a = s.split("(?<=\\G.{2})");
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this works? Kudos for the answer btw :)

Comment: I simplified expr a little, it also makes it easier to explain: matcher goes forward until it sees 2 chars behind and makes a split, \\G (last match) makes it continue after matched chars

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
public Date splitTimeByLength(String time) throws ParseException{
    String splitPattern = time.length() > 4 ? "hhmmssSS" : "hhmm";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(splitPattern);
    return sdf.parse(time);
}
```

More information: [SimpleDateFormat api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)